# Eclipse plugin : getBundle resource within JavaFX Platform

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I have run into a bit of a problem.  I am developing a plugin in eclipse and I am using JavaFX to create my GUI's for face detection.  The problem is I need to get resources from my bundle which are of the type "org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;" while I have imported "import javafx.application.Platform;" in order to update the Ui like so:

```
  Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
       public void run()
       {
          frameView.setImage(tmp);
        }
       });

       }
       }
    };
```

As you can see there is a conflict between imports if I was to try and import "org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;" to use "Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("Recognise");"

Is there any way to access this bundle while JavaFX Platform is imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the fully-qualified class name for one of them (specifically, for the one you don't import):

```
import javafx.application.Platform ;

// ...

Platform.runLater(() -> { /* ... */});

// ...

Bundle bundle = org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle("Recognise");
```